# What are the names of General Grievous' flagships?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, general-grievous

I already know of the *Invisible Hand* from *Revenge of the Sith*. Did General Grievous have another flagship or flagships, and, if so, what were their names?

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Malevolence

Comment: okay, so the Malevolence. Any others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Malevolence was a heavy cruiser that Grievous used as his flagship before it was destroyed by Anakin Skywalker. After that, he used the Invisible Hand as his next flagship.

Link: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Malevolence